# ROS kinetic Instulation Error (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and Ubuntu so apologies for asking a question on probably a simple fix. I am trying to install the ROS full Desktop with the following command on a dual booted dell precision 5520 with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full

After running this command I get the following end message.

53 upgraded, 838 newly installed, 0 to remove and 244 not upgraded.
Need to get 529 MB/530 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2,453 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]

What do i need to do in order to fix the issue?

If i say yes will this mess anything up?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339414/ros-kinetic-instulation-error-(ubuntu-16.04-lts)/) by [Aust](https://answers.ros.org/users/50084/aust/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2019-12-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aust](https://answers.ros.org/users/50084/aust/) on 2019-12-07**:
how to do I perform moderation to the question?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-08**:
You cannot. That's sort-of the point of the system: you'll have to wait for one of the moderators (ie: trusted site administrators) to log on and verify that you're not a spam-bot, then let your post through.

I've just done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The dialog is just asking if I would like to continue. Found a good answer to the question at the following website link. https://superuser.com/questions/287348/why-does-apt-get-sometimes-asks-for-confirmation/287357#287357

---

Originally posted by [Aust](https://answers.ros.org/users/50084/aust/) with karma: 18 on 2019-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-08**:\

> The dialog is just asking if I would like to continue.

Exactly, and just make it extra clear: this is just `apt` asking you this (ie: the Debian/Ubuntu package manager). It's not specific to ROS or a tool we've created.